# API Wordpress Customization

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning PHP and how customization works on Wordpress. I'm doing a tutorial where they give you this code

```
function test_customize_register( $wp_customize )
{
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'test_font_color' , array(
        'default'     => '#0000FF',
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'test_customize_section' , array(
        'title'      => __('Opciones Extra','my_test'),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'test_color', array(
        'label'      => __( 'Color de Testeo', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'    => 'test_customize_section',
        'settings'   => 'test_font_color'
    )));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'test_customize_register' );
```

And then this one

```
<?php
function test_customize_css() {
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'test_font_color' ) ) {
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('test_font_color'); ?>
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'test_customize_css');
?>
```

My question is, do I have to paste this two codes just in the way they are on `functions.php` or do I have to lock them into the `<?php` and `?>` labels (the two entire codes)? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are PHP functions, so they need to be enclosed in `<?PHP` `?>` tags. Whether you enclose both functions in one pair of tags, or use a separate pair of tags for each function is mostly a matter of preference. **Just make sure you're not putting PHP tags *inside* other PHP tags**

Comment: To the OP: Keep in mind that this is going into **functions.php**...which usually includes opening `<?php` tags at the beginning. Nested `<?php` tags would be bad...

Answer (score 0):

Just write `<?php` at start of `functions.php` file and then you can write any php code inside.